# WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor (minDate) doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, date, woocommerce

I have setup a date picker in my WooCommerce billing form, but I would like to restrict the user to only be able to pick dates AFTER the 6/Nov/2015.

I have added  + 5 year option to the drop down by adding the following to functions.php: (Extending the Date Picker Year Range) https://docs.woothemes.com/document/checkout-field-editor/

And I have tried adapting the snippet from this page but I couldn't get it working: http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor-date-field-restrictions/

How are you supposed to define 06/11/2015 (DD/MM/YY) to be the minDate in javascript?

TIA

EDIT:

```
    <?php
add_filter( 'wp_footer' , 'woo_add_checkout_field_date_range_limit' );
/**
 * woo_add_checkout_field_date_range_limit
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
 * See: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max
*/
function woo_add_checkout_field_date_range_limit() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery( document ).ready( function ( e ) {
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery( "#proposed_date" ).datepicker({ minDate: 06, 11, 15 });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code please. "I couldn't get it working" is insufficient information for correction if your usage of Checkout Field Editor add on is actually the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation and all else being well try

```
jQuery( "#date" ).datepicker({ minDate: "+D06 +M11 +Y2015" });
```

or

```
jQuery( "#date" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2015, 11, 6) });
```

Comment: This worked on an external test I think I'm just having issues with the id of the form item on the WooCommerce version. Thanks though!